# how to do grouping in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0

I'm trying to do a LINQ query to a list of RelatedProducts objects. I have to group them by CategoryId so I'm using the group by clause. Unfortunatly I just realized I can't simply use 'select g.Value' at the end. The group is a IGrouping and I want to return just the RelatedProduct here. How can I do this?

Also in my case a product can be in 2 categories at once, so how can I prevent LINQ from returning duplicates? I'm only interested in the first category (actualy it doesn't matter as long it's assigned to that product).

```
var query = from rp in context.RelatedProducts
                    join p in context.Products on rp.ProductId2 equals p.ProductId
                    join pc in context.ProductCategories on p.ProductId equals pc.ProductId
                    where rp.ProductId1 == productId1 &&
                    !p.Deleted &&
                    (showHidden || p.Published)
                    orderby rp.DisplayOrder
                    group rp by pc.CategoryId into g
                    select g;
```

Comment: If you are only interested in the first category, then why not just add where pc.CategoryId == interestingcategory instead of grouping, and then discarding all groups except the first?

Comment: when I said there are more categories I mean there is many-to-many relationship between Products and Categories. That's just how the database I'm working against is structured. I'm actually only using one category per product.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to do it like this:

```
List<RelatedProduct> relatedProducts = new List<RelatedProduct>();
        foreach (var group in query)
        {
            var key = group.Key;
            relatedProducts.AddRange(group.ToList());
        }
```

Comment: In that case could'nt you have slapped a .SelectMany(g => g).ToList() on the query and get the same ?

Comment: I could have if I knew how :)) That was the kind of answer I expected :D

Answer (score 0):

In your case `g` is `IEnumerable` so you can just use `select g.First()` or apply any kind of additional filtering to it.